# Warp10 query doesn't return last values (NOW -n)

Tags: fetch, warp10

i would like to get some values in my Warp10 db and the param -n doesn't work for me.

I have more than 1000 records in my db, and i want only the last 10 values:

```js
query = `[ '${token}' '~bucket.data' { } NOW -10 ] FETCH`
```

But this query return me all the values in my db, what's wrong with it ?

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed with the following PR: https://github.com/senx/warp10-platform/pull/614.

Download the latest Warp 10 version and this will be fixed. https://www.warp10.io/download